# Connect a Mongodb Docker Container Running on Server to Robo 3t on my Computer

Tags: mongodb, docker, ssh

I'm trying to deploy my first web app and I decided that it would be a good training to be able to connect my empty Mongo DB (inside its own docker container) itself running in a Digital Ocean server to Robo3t on my computer. 
I could find several guides explaining how to either do it for a DB running directly on the server or inside a container but not on a remote server. 
To be honest I'm a bit lost right now because I'm still completely new to these things. So I don't even what's the strategy I need to use...

Your help will be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind ports when you build the image with -p 80:80 for example. Change 80 with your port. Next step is open port in the remote machine. So then you can connect Roboto 3T with your db.